# How to use $pull with TypeORM to delete an object insude array using Mngodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, typeorm

I have a collection in mongodb with a schema :

```
{ 
"_id" : "",
 "vins" : [ { "field" : "" } ], 
"xyz" : "", 
"password" : "", 
"username" : ""
 }
```

I want to delete object inside the "vins" array that match a particular condition. Normally this is possible very easily using the "$pull" operator. But I wasn't able to find anything regarding how to do it using TypeORM.
  (It's worth mentioning that I have little to no experience using typeorm and have instead used mongoose throughout my career).

When I try

```
this.repo.update({ "xyz" : <value>} ,{ $pull : { "fields" : { "field": <value> } } })
```

I get an error

> Argument of type '{ $pull: { "vins": { "vin": any; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and '$pull' does not exist in type 'DeepPartial'

Comment: [FindOneAndUpdate](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/74dfebf06f917f1d6e79208903d00c8d4858df08/src/repository/MongoRepository.ts#L215) looks quite straightforward and not much different from mongoose or native driver. Did you try it?

Comment: The typescript compiler is giving this err   
`Argument of type '{ $pull: { "vins": { "vin": any; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<User>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '$pull' does not exist in type 'DeepPartial<User>' `   
when I try this query 
`this.repo.update({ "xyz" : <value>} ,{ $pull : {  "fields" : { "field":  <value>  } } })`   .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `MongoRepository` has `updateOne` and `updateMany` methods that permit this. I could get a test to compile and function using `updateOne`, for example.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/2bb0e398f922561f1cbb8ebbb19d20aa093e8bc2/src/repository/MongoRepository.ts#L356

Example usage:

```js
  const user = new User();
  user.firstName = "Timber";
  user.lastName = "Saw";
  user.flags = ["typescript", "nodejs"];

  const repo = getMongoRepository(User);
  await repo.save(user);
  console.log("Saved");

  await repo.updateOne({ _id: user.id }, { $pull: { flags: { $in: ["typescript"] } } });
  console.log("Updated!");
```

Comment: The updateOne method gives me error `Property 'updateOne' does not exist on type 'UserRepository'`

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaShujaat, you really need to provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I agree with Brasten - typeorm has no update method but updateOne and updateMany.

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to make it work with :

```
let mongoRepository = getMongoRepository(Repo);  
let result =  await  mongoUserRepository.findOneAndUpdate({ "field1" : value} , {  $pull: {"fields" :{"field":  value}  }} );
```

It appears that the method I was looking for was available in mongoRepository but not in the typeorm "Repository".